# failed to connect mongodb

Tags: mongodb

A few days ago I tried to run my server with mongoDB(with - `npm run dev`), and I didn't have any problems. Now I always get this network error.

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shard-00-02-fq3bp.mongodb.net:27017 closed
    [1]     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\itaya\Desktop\Itay\Dog_App\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:352:9)
    [1]     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
    [1]     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    [1]     at _handle.close (net.js:597:12)
    [1]     at TCP.done (_tls_wrap.js:388:7)
    [1]   name: 'MongoNetworkError',
    [1]   errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
    [1]   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: Is your db local? Or is it hosted on a website

Comment: Yes, my db local.

Comment: Try ``sudo service mongod start``

Comment: Please check IP whitelist or firewall. My case by default Atlas mongodb allowed only my PC's IP. Hence blocked from AWS. Navigate to setting add your system IP address on the white-list section.